# How to reduce the spacing between two div row containers using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something that looks like this:
[image]

And I'd like to reduce the spacing between two containers which are Fatal Police Shootings in US.
My code for these containers looks like this

```
    <h3 class="display-1 text-center mt-5 mb-5"> Data Science Projects </h3>

    <div id="container"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

      <a href="data_science_projects/Fatal_Police_Shootings_in_the_US.html"><img src="images/DS.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image" width="300px"></a>
      <br>
      <h6 class="text-center text-black"> Fatal Police Shootings in US </h6>

    </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">

      <a href="data_science_projects/Fatal_Police_Shootings_in_the_US.html"><img src="images/DS.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image" width="300px"></a>
      <br>
      <h6 class="text-center text-black"> Fatal Police Shootings in US </h6>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to add container class in CSS stylesheet, as this:

```
.container {
     padding-right: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
}
```

But this does not work. How can I adjust the spacing?

++ below is my css:

```
h3{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h1{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h6{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
label{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
input{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
option{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

h1{
    color: #0e0c0a;
    font-weight: 900;
}


p{
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: -0.8px;
  color: #0e0c0a;
}

footer{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

p.bigfont{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

p.mediumfont{
    font-size: 1em;
}

body{background-color: #fefefa;}

#spacecontainer {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

button{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.btn{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}


button.buttonme{
    color: #FF7A5A;
    border: none;
    
}

button.buttonme:hover{
    background-color: #FF7A5A;
}

button.buttonproject{
    color: #00AAA0;
    border: none;
}
button.buttonproject:hover{
    background-color: #00AAA0;
}


button.buttoncontact{
    color: #428BCA;
    border: none;
}
button.buttoncontact:hover{
    background-color: #428BCA;
}

button.buttonsubmit{
    color: #663399  ;
    border: solid 1px #663399;
}
button.buttonsubmit:hover{
    background-color:#663399;
}

.fa {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  
  .fa-twitch {
    color: #6441a5;
  }

  .fa-github {
    color:  #2c2f33;
  }

  .fa-linkedin {
    color: #4875B4;
  }

  .fa-instagram {
    color: #CD486B;
  }


  .fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  body, html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("images/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956999.jpg");
  
    /* Full height */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
      
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }


.container {
     padding-right: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
}
```

++ This is HTML code:

```
  <body> 
    
    <div class="text-right mr-5">
        <a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn buttonproject mr-2 mt-3 rounded-0">Projects</button> </a>
        <a href="portfolio_me.html"> <button type="button" class="btn buttonme mr-2 mt-3 rounded-0">Biography</button> </a>
        <a href="portfolio_contact.html"> <button type="button" class="btn buttoncontact mr-2   mt-3 rounded-0">Contact</button> </a>
    </div>


    <h1 class="display-1 text-center mt-5 mb-5"> Sarah's Learning Log </h1>

    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">

      <a href="python_project.html"><img src="images/alien_invasion.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image" width="300px"></a>
      <br>
      <h6 class="text-center text-black"> Python Projects </h6>
  
    </div>
    
      <div class="col-lg-6">

      <a href="data_science_project.html"><img src="images/DS.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image" width="300px"></a>
      <br>
      <h6 class="text-center text-black"> Data Science Projects </h6>
  
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <footer class="text-center footer mt-5">
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/" class="fa fa-twitch mb-3 text-center"></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/" class="fa fa-github mb-3 text-center"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="fa fa-linkedin mb-3 text-center"></a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com/" class="fa fa-instagram mb-3 text-center"></a>
    <p>&copy; 2020 Sarah All Rights Reserved. </p>
  </footer>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: I think you are concerned about the columns, not the container since they are both in the same container and row. You don't want to kill the container padding because it offsets a negative row margin that is used for bumper space in responsive views, anyway.

Comment: I just think it looks weird that it has such a huge gap... is there any way to reduce the space? :-(

Comment: tbh, it's most likely some other CSS that you have something odd going on. Post a fiddle that has the complete css because those lg-6 should be split 50/50 and assuming they are, the second column would start around 50% page width, which is not, which means something else is going on.

Comment: I also tried to use 3 responsive images with ```<div class="col-lg-4">``` , but did not work. I just added the CSS, would you take a look at it, please?

Comment: let's see the rest of your html starting with `<body>`. also i hope you got a pie chart that's adjusted for percentage of population and not just total deaths which gives a way incorrectly skewed representation of fatal police shootings by race.

Comment: Thank you I just added it! And thank you for the advice on the chart, I'm still learning and lots to practice and learn. Those are just for my learning that I simply visualize the data that I found.. Thanks again!

Comment: Your code looks right to me. In terms of column width. https://jsfiddle.net/eau9gjbd/ maybe the images are too small? not sure tbh.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using more narrowed columns and centering them correctly with an offset class:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
    <a href="data_science_projects/Fatal_Police_Shootings_in_the_US.html"
      ><img
        src="images/DS.jpg"
        class="rounded mx-auto d-block"
        alt="Responsive image"
        width="300px"
    /></a>
    <br />
    <h6 class="text-center text-black">Fatal Police Shootings in US</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
    <a href="data_science_projects/Fatal_Police_Shootings_in_the_US.html"
      ><img
        src="images/DS.jpg"
        class="rounded mx-auto d-block"
        alt="Responsive image"
        width="300px"
    /></a>
    <br />
    <h6 class="text-center text-black">Fatal Police Shootings in US</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-bootstrap-centering-8elz8)

Comment: Hi! When I do this, my images all go to the left, instead of stay in the middle..

Comment: Good point. You can fix that using the `text-center` class on your column. I've adjusted the code and sandbox link.